# Firefox Addon SDK call js functions

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I've got an addon with a working callback construct:

lib/main.js:

```
function myLogin(loginname,loginfield) {
    var pageUrl = tabs.activeTab.url;
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;
    var worker=tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: data.url("content.js"),
      onAttach: function(worker) {
            console.log("pageMod.onAttach");
      }
    });
    worker.port.emit("doLogin", loginfield);

}
```

data/content.js:

```
self.port.on("doLogin", function(loginfield) {
    document.getElementById(loginfield).value="moo";
    document.getElementById(loginfield).focus();
    showSignInCaptcha();
});
```

I've got that all triggered by a button click in a sidebar.html which is not described here, I'll end up calling myLogin(). loginfield is a field on a website that is open in a tab. showSignInCaptcha() is a Javascript routine that is provided by the website open in the tab.

What is working / not working:

- I can fill the login field with "moo"
- I cannot call the function showSignInCaptcha()

How can I make that function call work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
        unsafeWindow.showSignInCaptcha();
```

does the job. Found that in the SDK docs: [Access objects defined by page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Access_objects_defined_by_page_scripts)